# "Unable to find an element with the text.." during react testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, graphql, apollo

I have a small React/TypeScript/GraphQL app that connects to an API, fetches products, and displays them on the page.

I'm trying to create a test that checks if the product's name is in the document after a GraphQL mock, by using `getByText`, but I keep getting `TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: iPad 5g. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.`

I also tried using `getByRole` (see below), but that gives me the error `TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "paragraph" and name '/month to month/i'`

Is there a better way to do this? How can I check if the name of the product rendered correctly? I appreciate any help.

**ProductCard.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import TestRenderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { MockedProvider } from '@apollo/client/testing';
import ProductCard from "../ProductCard";
import { LOAD_PRODUCTS } from "../GraphQL/Queries";
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

it('renders ProductCard successfully', async () => {
  const productMock = {
    request: {
      query: LOAD_PRODUCTS,
    },
    result: {
      data: { products: { productName: 'iPad 5g', code: 'i5g', price: 599.99 } },
    },
  };

  const component = TestRenderer.create(
    <MockedProvider mocks={[productMock]} addTypename={false}>
      <ProductCard displayName={productMock.result.data.products.productName} price={productMock.result.data.products.price} />
    </MockedProvider>,
  );
  await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));  
  expect(screen.getByText(`iPad 5g`)).toBeInTheDocument();
  // expect(screen.getByRole('paragraph', { name: /iPad 5g/i })).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

**ProductCard.tsx**

```
// imports 
// ... 
// ...

// TypeScript types 
// ... 
// ... 

const ProductCard: React.FC<Props> = ({ productName, price }) => {

  return (
    <>
      <Typography>{productName}</Typography>
      <Typography>{price}</Typography>
      <Typography><p>Great new features</p></Typography>
      <Button>Buy Now</Button>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have no need for `MockedProvider` if you're just testing a "dumb" component (aka one that just renders some HTML and has no other logic). You only need `MockedProvider` if you're testing a component that uses `useQuery` or `useMutation`, in which case those hooks would return the mock.result value you provide. Try removing the MockedProvider altogether and just render the component with some props and see if that helps.